# Opened up a stick-blender to retrieve its motor but the circuit board broke. What is the circuit I should reproduce?

Tags: disassembly

See question title and pictures. It’s plugged into 230v and has quite high rpm and torque. I’m trying to see if I can reuse this motor in a different application. [image: overview]
[image: frontcapacitor]
[image: resistor]
[image: back]
Edit: Looks like there is a diode on the opposite side of the capacitor as well

Comment: I’m afraid we don’t have many people experienced in motor circuits, we specialize more in software RE or at most simple microcontrollers. Electrical engineering SE is probably a better fit for this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on a different site.

Comment: Is it possible to move to EE?